# Trinidad custom jsf component

Tags: jsf-2, trinidad

Anyone have link with, step by step process (simple) of creating/updating the Trinidad jsf component?
I am trying to modify `<tr:inputText>` to accommodate predictive text and some more additional functionality in to it.

Comment: Tried dowbloading its source?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes i have the source. What i am trying to do here is .. like pat:inputText, which will have the actual trinidad input text functionality and override some of them, add some functions.

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem then. You can analyze how their component is created. Copy all that (it is 'just' a jsf component), change what is needed and build your own...

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks. But it looks very complex. TLD creation should be easier than copying everything and modifying, when the source code and implementation is already available in the Trinidad jar.

Comment: In your comment you talk about a `pat:imputText`. That is a new component in a new namespace. So youn need to copy everything that is needed (that word was missing in my previous comment). But ofcourse you can also try to create a composite component in which you use the trinidad inputText. But since that is 'just' plain jsf and not trinidad related, you can search for generic tutorials.